# getting review by id

Tags: magento2, controllers, review

I am trying to fetch review model by id for this i am using factory method below code

```
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory)
    {
        $this->reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }


public function execute()
    {
        // parse GET parameters
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('review_id');

            $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->load($id);
            die($review->getId);
}
```

but not getting anything. it just getting loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
echo $review->getId();
exit;
```

instead of

```
die($review->getId);
```

Comment: Oh yes :) its working Thanks. But why its not working with die